# How to ignore a word while capturing with a regex?

Tags: php, html, regex, special-characters

I have this string:

```
$text = "What&#039;s your #name ?"
```

And I have this code capturing 'name' and '039':

```
preg_replace("/\B#(\w+)/", "<a href='url'>#$1</a>", $text);
```

Any idea about how to capture 'name' but not '039'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a negative lookbehind:

```
echo preg_replace("/(?<!\S)#(\w+)/", "<a href='url'>#$1</a>", $text);
```

Regex autopsy:

- `(?<!\S)` - A negative lookbehind - to assert that the `#` is not preceded by a non-whitespace character
- `#` - matches the `#` character literally
- `(\w+)` - first capturing group

[**Regex101 demo.**](http://regex101.com/r/tA7sK4)

Comment: How would I capture this <#name> as well @Amal Murali ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you explain?

Comment: For example, in this string "What&#039;s your #name <#name> or [#name]?", I would like to capture the 3 'name'. @Amal Murali

Comment: @lokiloq: That's a different problem. Please [ask a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

You could use `[A-Za-z]+` instead of `\w+`.